# How Delphi "Tools - Options - Environment Options - Delphi Options - Library-Win32 - Libary path" (for dcu's) is named in Delphi 10.X (Sydney)?

Tags: delphi

I am using "Tools - Options - Environment Options - Delphi Options - Library-Win32 - Libary path" variable to keep the semicolon-separated lists of paths for the directories in which I am keeping *.dcu files (Delphi compiled units) in the older Delphi versions, e.g. Delphi 2009.

Now I have Delphi 10.4 Sydney and it does not have such option. Which Delphi 10.4 Sydney option replaced the older Library path?

My guess is that Delphi 10.4 used 'Tools - Options - IDE - Environment Variables - System Variables - BDSBIN' or its 'User Sytem Overrides' as the Library Path. But I have confusion about this, becase my installation contains the value "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\bin" currenty and I am afraid to put additional directories here. The name "BDSBIN" seems so venerable that it may be allowed to contain only one directory only? Or is it possible to add semicolon-separated directory list here as well?

Context: I am trying to use https://github.com/theilgaz/FGX in my Delphi 10.4 Sydney and it puts all the dcu files beside the pas files. So - my intention was to copy dcu files in the separate library directory and add this directory to the Library Path and I am not sure wheter the BDSBIN is the library path for Delphi 10.4 Sydney or should I look in other Delphi 10.4 Sydney environment variable for the list of library paths?

Comment: Tools->Options->Language->Delphi->Library. `$BDSBIN` is the location of the Delphi IDE binaries. `BDS` is Borland Development Studio, and `BIN` is BINaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since Embarcadero released its first RAD Studio in 2010 both Delphi and former C++ builder share the same IDE.

So in order for IDE to now support two programming languages at the same time certain options that are language specific had to be grouped together.

This is why you can now fin the mentioned Library settings in [Tools>Options>Language>Delphi Options>Library](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Library) instead.

And if you would have C++ builder licence as well then the library path settings would be found in [Tools>Options>Language>C++ Options>Paths and Directories](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Paths_and_Directories_(C%2B%2B))